# SQL display all name branches by distinct where barcode = '25122225 '

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Updated_SQLSOLD` with field name `Branch`, `Barcode`. I have more than 10k unique barcodes for the 10 branches and not all barcodes are registered into all branches. but I need to display 10 branches even if I find barcodes for 7 branches only.

Example.

```
 [Branch]     [Barcode]
----------------------
  branch1  |  25122225
  branch2  |  25122225
  branch3  |  25122225
  branch4  |  25122225
  branch5  |  33333333
  branch6  |  33333333
  branch7  |  66666666
  branch8  |  25122225
  branch9  |  56565656
  branch10 |  56565656
  branch1  |  55444444
  branch1  |  56565656
  branch2  |  56565656
  branch3  |  56565656
```

```sql
SELECT [Branch], [Barcode]
FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD]
where [Barcode] = '25122225'
```

Result is:

```
 [Branch]     [Barcode]
----------------------
  branch1  |  25122225
  branch2  |  25122225
  branch3  |  25122225
  branch4  |  25122225
  branch8  |  25122225
```

Now how to display all branches even if no serial is available, like this:

```
 [Branch]     [Barcode]
----------------------
  branch1  |  25122225
  branch2  |  25122225
  branch3  |  25122225
  branch4  |  25122225
  branch5  |  Null
  branch6  |  Null
  branch7  |  Null
  branch8  |  25122225
  branch9  |  Null
  branch10 |  Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all available branches in a subquery and work with it.

```
SELECT tbBranch.Branch, BarCode
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Branch
    FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD]
)tbBranch 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD] A
ON A.Branch = tbBranch.Branch
AND A.BarCode = '25122225'
```

Comment: subquery ( even having distinct clause ) is not needed. Refer : [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=656ba291342080b20638fe73a6e4951d)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a left join

```
SELECT a.[Branch], a1.[Barcode] 
FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD] a
LEFT JOIN [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD] a1
ON a.[Branch]=a1.[Branch] AND a.[Barcode] = '25122225'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT us.Branch,
       MAX(CASE WHEN us.Barcode = '25122225' THEN us.Barcode END) as Barcode
FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].Updated_SQLSOLD us
GROUP BY Barcode;
```

I would recommend a `JOIN` when you have a separate list of branches:

```
SELECT b.Branch, MAX(us.Barcode) as Barcode
FROM branches b LEFT JOIN
     [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD] us
     ON us.branch = b.branch AND us.Barcode = '25122225'
GROUP BY b.branch;
```